# How to replicate a figure with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the figure using the Latex own figure making capabilities.

[image]

Searching I found the TikZ module, which draws nice figures within Latex, don't know how to start with this one.

Comment: Welcome! It is absolutely straightforward to draw this, but you may want to provide the texts as texts such that users do not have to type them in from a screen shot.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, are you alive? Tks, I just edited the image replacing the text with trivial letters. I hope this helps

Comment: You should read the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) especially the tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=stealth,thick]
 \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (8,0) node[midway,below] {ble ble};
 \draw[<->] (0,0.5) -- ++ (4,0) node[pos=0.3,above]{bla bla};
 \draw[<->] (8,0.5) -- ++ (-2.5,0) node[pos=0.95,anchor=south west]{CCCCC};
 \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (8,1.5) -- ++ (-4.5,0)
     node[midway,above=2pt]{AAAA};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]